# Classe Abstrata em Python, como escolher implementação

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou aprendendo python e tentando fazer um programa onde tenho uma classe abstrata e duas subclasses que implementam tal. Preciso fazer uma outra classe que vai escolher qual implemntação usar a depender do usuário, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Se alguem puder me indicar algum material de estudo pra essa parte de POO me ajudaria muito! Não encontrei nada que me ajudasse nessa parte de classe abastrata.

Segue a parte do código. O BaseDificultador que não sei como fazer.

```
class Dificultador(object):
#classe abstrata que vai ser super classe de DificultadorNivel e DificultadorTipo
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
__metaclass__ = ABCMeta
@abstractmethod
def Sort(self, expressoes):
    pass

class DificultadorNivel(Dificultador):#Faz um sort da lista de expressoes em niveis
def Sort(self, expressoes):
    expressoes = FonteDeExpressoes().lista()
    expnivel = sorted(expressoes, key=lambda x: x.nivel)
    return expnivel

class DificultadorTipo(Dificultador):#Faz um sort da lista de expressoes em tipo
def Sort(self, expressoes):
    expressoes = FonteDeExpressoes().lista()
    exptipo = sorted(expressoes, key=lambda x: x.tipo)
    return exptipo

class BaseDificultador(Dificultador):
#Funciona como um switch de seleção para escolha do sort
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma mais simples de escolher qual objeto instânciar dependendo de alguma condição do programa é usar uma função para isso.

O nome "complicado" é "factory function" ou "factory method". Em algumas outras linguagens OOP, você ter que usar uma factory function implica em alguma complicação já que a função em si tem que ficar em outra classe (as vezes construída artificialmente só para isso), mas em Python é algo bem direto:

```
def obtem_dificultador(parametros):
    if (condicao):
          return DificultadorNivel(parametros)
    else:
        return DificultadorTipo(parametros)
```

Ou, como as classes são simplesmente objetos que são chamáveis para serem instanciados, sua seleção da classe pode simplesmente retornar a classe - que vai ser instanciada com o s parametros desejados só por quem a chamou.
Mais ainda, se forem várias classes, você pode referenciar suas classes numa estrutura de dados, como um dicionário, o que pode permitir obter a classe desejada de forma mais limpa que uma longa sequência de if/elif/else.

Claro que Python é dinâmica o bastante para você *poder* trocar a classe, ou o compartamento, de uma subclasse dentro dos próprios mecânismos de instanciar a classe (em geral no método `__new__`)  - mas aí, como está na resposta do @Cigano, não é considerado uma boa prática. Factory functions são boas.

Em Python também é possível, para classes definidas em código Python, trocar diretamente o atributo `__class__` de um objeto já instanciado - efetivamente trocando a classe de um objeto existente. (Claro que uma prática dessas difilmente seria defensável, sem ser para fins de demonstração. Os atributos do objeto e a inicialização foi toda da classe antiga)

Se for um projeto grande, e precisar de mecanismos sofisticados para escolher a classe, pde ser o caso de ser mais vantaem usar a Zope Component Architecture - um framework de componentização (que só tem o nome "Zope" - não é o Zope inteiro) 
http://muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html

(A implementação da forma correta da classe abstrata é como está na resposta do Cigano - mas em Python não é algo tão necessário -  a não ser que você realmente vá ter uma estrutura grande e corra o risco de se atrapalhar com o que cada classe precisa implementar ou não (sub-classes de classes abstratas que estejam com métodos faltantes vão dar erro no momento em que sua declaração for processada) )

Answer (score 3):

Classes abstratas no Python são implementadas usando o módulo [`abc`](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). O correto seria algo assim (considerando Python 3.4 e superiores):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Dificultador(ABC):
    '''classe abstrata que vai ser super classe de DificultadorNivel e DificultadorTipo'''
    @abstractmethod
    def Sort(self, expressoes):
        pass
```

As demais classes ficam assim:

```
class DificultadorNivel(Dificultador):
    '''Faz um sort da lista de expressoes em niveis'''
    def Sort(self, expressoes):
        expressoes = FonteDeExpressoes().lista()
        expnivel = sorted(expressoes, key=lambda x: x.nivel)
        return expnivel

class DificultadorTipo(Dificultador):
    '''Faz um sort da lista de expressoes em tipo'''
    def Sort(self, expressoes):
        expressoes = FonteDeExpressoes().lista()
        exptipo = sorted(expressoes, key=lambda x: x.tipo)
        return exptipo
```

Não precisa implementar `BaseDificultador`. Isto vai contra o [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Não conhecia o SOLID.
Mas como eu posso selecionar qual vai sobreescrever? Eu tentei fazer funções ao invés de classe mas ocoreu o seguinte erro:

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Dificultador with abstract methods Sort

Comment: Poder até pode, mas isso vai ficar terrivelmente complexo. Vai contra a cultura do Python.

Comment: Você não pode instanciar `Dificultador` justamente porque é uma classe abstrata. Precisa de uma explicação sobre o que é uma classe abstrata?